# How to use parameters of one subchart in another subchart in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a Helm chart containing two subcharts, `charts/subchart1` and `charts/subchart2`.  Each of the subcharts has its own `values.yaml`, `templates/deployment.yaml`, and similar files.

In the parent chart's `values.yaml` file I am using a parameter like:

```yaml
subchart1:
  serverPort: 1234
```

I can use this value from subchart1.

However, I want to use the same value in the `subchart2/templates/service.yaml` file.  Accessing using `{{ .Values.subchart1.serverPort }}` is not working.  Is there any way to access it?

Comment: Obviously it will not work. You can only access the values from parent chart which is defined under global or should be defined under the name of the subchart in parent values.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable, but it will be more complicated.

❗❗❗ You may need to learn a few concepts first.

1. [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)
2. [Dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)
3. [Exports and Imports values](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#importing-child-values-via-dependencies)

---

Here is an example:

demo struct

```
multi
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
│   ├── sub0
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── charts
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── configmap.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   └── sub1
│       ├── Chart.yaml
│       ├── charts
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── configmap.yaml
│       └── values.yaml
├── templates
│   └── configmap.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

- multi: parent chart
- sub0: sub-chart 0
- sub1: cub-chart 1

We will show how to use `test1: t1` in `sub1`, which defined in `sub0`

multi/charts/sub0/templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cm
data:
  sub0: {{ .Values.sub0 }}
  g0: {{ .Values.global.test0 }}
  g1: {{ .Values.global.test1 }}
```

multi/charts/sub0/values.yaml

```yaml
sub0: sub0

global:
  test0: t0

exports:
  data:
    global:
      test1: t1
```

multi/charts/sub1/templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cm
data:
  sub1: {{ .Values.sub1 }}
  g1: {{ .Values.global.test1 }}
  g2: {{ .Values.global.test2 }}
```

multi/charts/sub1/values.yaml

```yaml
sub1: sub1
```

multi/templates.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cm
data:
  dessert: {{ .Values.parent }}
  g1: {{ .Values.global.test1 }}
  g2: {{ .Values.global.test2 }}
```

multi/values.yaml

```yaml
parent: parent

global:
  test2: t2
```

❗ multi/Chart.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: multi
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: "1.16.0"

dependencies:
  - name: sub0
    repository: file://./charts/sub0
    version: 0.1.0
    import-values:
      - data
```

---

`helm --dry-run --debug template multi .`

```yaml
---
# Source: multi/charts/sub0/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: multi-cm
data:
  sub0: sub0
  g0: t0
  g1: t1
---
# Source: multi/charts/sub1/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: multi-cm
data:
  sub1: sub1
  g1: t1
  g2: t2
---
# Source: multi/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: multi-cm
data:
  dessert: parent
  g1: t1
  g2: t2
```

---

As you can see, `sub1` reads `{{ .Values.global.test1 }}` from `parent-chart (multi)` by accessing global values.

But this value `{{ .Values.global.test1 }}` is not directly defined in `multi/values.yaml`, but is derived from `sub0`, and then ``multi`imports this value through`dependency```

Since the value of parent-chart in sub-chart needs to be accessed through the `global value`, the global value is written in the `values.yaml` of sub0

Of course, if you only need `sub1` to access the value in `sub0`, name can directly `dependency` the value in `sub0` in a similar way in `sub1`.

And our above approach will be accessible in all sub-charts.